# Symfony 5 Testcase

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony

I have created the service class which contains one method to get the latest number from 3rd party website json file and one more service for http and in that I have get method.

Now I need to test the service class method

so far what I tried I might be wrong but didn't get any success

[image: Service class which uses the http service to get the data]

[image: Http service class which has get method]

```
    public function testSuccess(): void
{

    $mockApiClient = $this->createMock(HttpService::class);
    $mockApiClient->method('getRequest')
        ->willReturn([
        'success' => false
    ]);

    $parameterBagInterface = $this->createMock(ParameterBagInterface::class);

    $dt['url']='https://example.com/';
    $dt['type']='/test.json';
    $dt['limit']='10';
    $parameterBagInterface->expects($this->once())
        ->method('get')
        ->willReturn($dt);

    $service = new WebcomicService(
        $mockApiClient,
        $parameterBagInterface
    );

    // Act
    $result = $service->lastestWebcomicNumber();
}
```

Comment: Mock classes only have the functions you give them, really. So instead of your mock having `getRequest` you probably want it to have `getData()` which should return a `Response` object, which you can design yourself, essentially. your parameterbaginterface mock looks okay so far.

Comment: I am getting null after setting my desire response The way you suggested

Comment: can you please show your updated code?

Comment: Testcase
        $mockApiClient->method('getData')
            ->willReturn(['status' => false]);

Comment: public function getData(string $url, $type= 'json'): array
    {
        $response =  $this->client->request(
            'GET',
            $url
        );
        if($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {

            $data = ($type == 'xml') ?  $response->getContent() : $response->toArray();

            return [
                "data" => $data,
                "status" => true
            ];
        }
        return [
            "data" => [],
            "status" => false
        ];
    }

Comment: Update HttpService: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fCCeeZ6YTy1-GspoUNqCmLXj4f3IN0UQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: this looks very different from your former HttpService. do you get any error messages?

Comment: Yes I updated the Http Service code now so that I can return array instead of ResponseInterface

Comment: when I run testcase it returns Failed asserting that null is false.

Comment: your code doesn't reflect this error message at all, since the assertion (and relevant code) is missing. It's really hard to help or even see the problem, when your code is in constant flux.

Comment: Updated Testcase: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OBGwQBwHLeRxyZfSICjwv1VXw6t0zE9g/view?usp=sharing

Comment: well, your `lastestWebcomicNumber()` (sic!) function returns an int (unless that also has changed) and since `$result` now is an int `$result['success']` is (apart from being bad and an error) `null` thus ... yes, `null` isn't `false`.